# What does "profile" mean?

Tags: meaning

I'm reading a book about database and below is an excerpt.

> AOAG is the most appropriate technology for high availability in scenarios where you have small databases with low write profiles.

Here *AOAG* is the name of a database technology. For a database, you can write to it or read from it. What does *low write profiles* mean here? From the context I guess it means *low write volume*. But I can't find this meaning in the dictionary.

Comment: That's technical jargon. Consider asking in [Database Administrators SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for the meaning of a specific technical term and not about learning the English language.

Comment: Are you guys sure it's a technical term? I know this technology and it doesn't look like a technical term for me.

Comment: Your conjecture seems sound to me but I am not a database person.